# How to define height of a container by an element within that container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to define the height of my container based off of the image within that container using jquery or javascript. Is this possible? My code is as follows:

```
<div class="img-info">
<img src="images/photos/thumb_sample_l.jpg" alt="sample" title="Sample thumbnail" width="100%" />
</div>
```

Comment: Generally containers will take on the height of their content implicitly.

Comment: The default value of the css height (and width, in fact) property is automatically computed by the browser to be big enough to hold whatever is in it

Comment: Perhaps OP is trying to set the height by the image, then let the rest of the content overflow with a scrollbar?

Comment: try this: `$('.img-info').height($('.img-info > img').height())`

Comment: Raminson, this works perfectly!
Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the javascript code to manage your content height according to the screen height may be helpful for you..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var scrheight=screen.availHeight;
  //alert(scrheight-270);
  $('.TabbedPanelsContent').css('max-height',scrheight-270);
  $('.TabbedPanelsContent').css('overflow','auto');
  });
  </script>
```

use your class name instead of TabbedPanelsContent here will made you want u want.

Comment: Thanks abc123, this also will come in handy with the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery script should do the trick

```
var imgHeight = $('.img-info img').height();
$('.img-info').css({'height':imgHeight});
```